# apache2 redirect http to https in vagrant box

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, shell, vagrant

I am trying to achieve apache2 http redirect to https in vagrant. Below is my `Vagrantfile` and `bootstrap.sh` script. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here in case of vagrant box. I am using ubuntu 16.04 vagrant image.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.hostname = "suffire"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080, protocol: "tcp"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: 8443, protocol: "tcp"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.1.10"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

Bootstrap script is as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# ---------------------------------------
#          Virtual Machine Setup
# ---------------------------------------

# Adding multiverse sources.
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/multiverse.list << EOF
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
EOF


# Updating packages
apt-get update

sudo sed -ie 's/^mesg/#mesg/' /root/.profile

# ---------------------------------------
#          Apache Setup
# ---------------------------------------

# Installing Packages
apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-fastcgi git-core
apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-mbstring php7.0-gd php7.0-intl php7.0-xml php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-zip php-pecl-http php-pecl-http-dev

# Add ServerName to httpd.conf
httpd=$(cat <<EOF
ServerName localhost
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
EOF
)

echo $httpd > /etc/apache2/conf-available/httpd.conf 

cert=$(cat <<EOF
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
EOF
)

newkey=$(cat <<EOF
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF
)

echo $cert > /etc/apache2/server.crt
echo $newkey > /etc/apache2/server.key

chmod 400 /etc/apache2/server.key
chmod 400 /etc/apache2/server.crt

# Setup hosts file
VHOST=$(cat <<EOF
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/server.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
EOF
)

echo "${VHOST}" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

VHOST1=$(cat <<EOF
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  ServerName localhost
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  Redirect permanent / https://localhost
</VirtualHost>
EOF
)

echo "${VHOST1}" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


# Loading needed modules to make apache work
a2enmod actions fastcgi rewrite ssl
a2ensite default-ssl.conf
a2ensite 000-default.conf
service apache2 reload
```

Note: I've tested http redirect to https on 16.04 which works fine however it is not working in case of vagrant box. procedure is same.

Objective here is apache2 should be able to do following.
Ubuntu 16.04 host(8080) --> Ubuntu 16.04 guest(80) --> redirect guest 443
Ubuntu 16.04 host(8443) --> Ubuntu 16.04 guest(443)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_SCHEME} ^http$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

If not, log into your vagrant box and see if those lines are there in your config. Then have apache rewrite you to http://example.com/%{REQUEST_SCHEME} to see what it thinks you're coming in on.